# Threads with decorators

Tags: python, multithreading, decorator

I'm trying to implement threading(with using decorators) to my application, but can't understand some things about locks and managing threads.

```
import threading

def run_in_thread(fn):
    def run(*k, **kw):
        t = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=k, kwargs=kw)
        t.start()
    return run

class A:
    @run_in_thread
    def method1(self):
        for x in range(10000):
            print x


    @run_in_thread
    def method2(self):
        for y in list('wlkefjwfejwiefwhfwfkjshkjadgfjhkewgfjwjefjwe'):
            print y

    def stop_thread(self):
        pass

c = A()
c.method1()
c.method2()
```

1. As I understand, method1 and method2 are not synchronized, but synchronizing of that stuff implementing with help of locks. How I can add locks to my decorator-function?
2. How can I realize method for stopping long threads using decorators?

Comment: What is it you want to synchronize between the two threads?

Comment: May be I said something incorrect.
I want to have possibility in some cases(not always) run second thread after 1 thread, not parallel.

Comment: Surely the simple way to do that is to not run the code in a thread in that case.  In which case you could have two similar methods, one which does the task in a thread and one that doesn't.  Alternatively pass in a parameter when calling which indicates if the call is to be threaded or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you extend the function to

```
def run_in_thread(fn):
    def run(*k, **kw):
        t = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=k, kwargs=kw)
        t.start()
        return t # <-- this is new!
    return run
```

i. e., let the wrapper function return the created thread, you can do

```
c = A()
t1 = c.method1()
t1.join() # wait for it to finish
t2 = c.method2()
# ...
```

i. e, get the thread where the original method runs in, do whatever you want with it (e. g. join it) and only then call the next method.

If you don't need it in a given case, you are free to omit it.

Comment: can you explain a bit more of what's going on in this code here?

Comment: @Skyler Done so.

Comment: The issue here that you changing the type of the method. Instead returning None (or any type the method defined to return) the decorator caouse it to return Thread.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you want to synchronize the two threads you simply need to add locks inside the decorated functions, not the decorators themselves.
2. There is not a simple way to directly stop a Thread, only way is to use an Event to signal the thread it must exit.

For threading decorators you can take a look at [pebble](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble/1.1.0).

Comment: Looks very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Semaphores could help in decorators, something like this - calculating factorial numbers from 1 to 1000:

```
import threading

from functools import wraps
from math import factorial


DIC = {}

def limit(number):
    ''' This decorator limits the number of simultaneous Threads
    '''
    sem = threading.Semaphore(number)
    def wrapper(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args):
            with sem:
                return func(*args)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper

def async(f):
    ''' This decorator executes a function in a Thread'''
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thr = threading.Thread(target=f, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thr.start()
    return wrapper

@limit(10)     # Always use @limit as the outter decorator
@async
def calcula_fatorial(number):
    DIC.update({number: factorial(number)})

@limit(10)
def main(lista):
    for elem in lista:
        calcula_fatorial(elem)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pprint import pprint
    main(range(1000))
    pprint(DIC)
```