# Python decorator with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-decorators

I want to create a decorator that can let function run in its own thread.
And I also want to use a queue as the decorator's arg, so that I can get the function's return value.
Like this:

```
import queue
result = queue.Queue
@thread(result)
def function(args):
    print ("Hello World!")
    return args
function("Hello Everyone!")
print (result.get())
```

Preconceived, the code will get this output:

> Hello World!
>
> Hello Everyone!

So I write code like this:

```
def thread(resultQueue = None):
    def wrapper(function):
        def process(*args, **kwargs):
            ret = function(*args, **kwargs)
            if resultQueue : resultQueue.put(ret)
            return resultQueue
        thread = threading.Thread(target = process)
        thread.setDaemon(True)
        thread.start()
        return process
    return wrapper
a = queue.Queue()

@basic.thread(a)
def test(arg):
    print (arg)
    time.sleep(3)
    return arg[::-1]
test("Hello World!")
print ("Hello!")
print (a.get())
```

But I got this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 911, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 859, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 214, in process
    ret = function(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'
```

Why I got this exception and how can I fix that?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234547/threads-with-decorators If you need an explanation let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new `Thread` in the `wrapper` function. Instead, you need to define a new method inside it which will create Thread.

```
def thread(resultQueue=None):
    def wrapper(function):
        def pw(*args, **kwargs):
            def process(*args, **kwargs):
                # print(args, kwargs)
                ret = function(*args, **kwargs)
                if resultQueue:
                    resultQueue.put(ret)
                # return resultQueue
            thread = threading.Thread(target=process, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
            thread.setDaemon(True)
            thread.start()
            return process
        return pw
    return wrapper
```

And you also need to pass arguments to the Thread constructor. This is the reason you are getting the Error.